# How to extract values from string of (key, value) pairs using RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that extracts the values from two specific key,value pairs in a string, i.e.:

```
key1=<key1here>key2=<key2here>key3=<key3here>...
```

And I only want to capture the values for keys 1 and 2. Is there a way to construct a pattern which would only pull the specific values for keys 1 and 2 for a match?

Comment: can you provide an example input and output?

Comment: @chase So for example:

**Input**: `key1=fookey2=barkey3=baz`
**Output (assuming key1 and key2 are desired)**: `[foo,bar]`

Comment: I see no need for Regex - Would'nt a line of js do the job too?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution (involving `RegExp`) is to split on every key, leaving you with an array of values.

```js
const regex = /key\d+=/g;
const input = 'key1=fookey2=barkey3=baz';
const [, ...output] = input.split(regex);
console.log(output);
```